# Assertion failure when adding Particle SpriteKit particle file in Xcode 6.0

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, assertion, particles

I'm working with xcode 6.0.1 and when I add a new file of type SpriteKit Particle and **push the button  SKNode Inspector** to edit the properties, an assertion is produced.

The error is:

```
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-6528/IDEKit/Inspectors/IDEInspectorCategoryController.m:159
Details:  **All objects must have type identifiers**, <SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {760, 659}}, represented by <SKDocumentNavigableItem 0x7f8d3d71e0d0: (supports Any SKScene, represents: <SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {760, 659}})> does not.
Function: NSSet *IDETypeIdentifiersForNavigables(NSArray *__strong)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f8d39e19c20>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
```

This error is launched when I push the button in the XCODE IDE SKnode Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error using Xcode 6.01.

Open xcode, but select "Don't reopen pen". No clue what to do next.